# Http request stuck in the IIS webserver post authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis

We are having an IIS hosted web service and randomly some incoming requests get stuck post authentication. I have added some logging in the code but the call is not reaching the corresponding application code. Here is the sample call failing. 
 `http://localhost/FlighterPhx/api/AbConfigOperations/GetABConfigBondFile&env=1&abConfigId=147114584.`

In [Http Authentication](http://qnimate.com/understanding-http-authentication-in-depth/), the first call returns 401 and then the caller presents the Authorization information but the second call is not hitting the application code.  Here is the entry in IIS logs:

```
2019-11-11 17:32:24 ::1 POST /FlighterPhx/api/AbConfigOperations/GetABConfigBondFile env=1&abConfigId=147114584 80 - ::1 - - 401 2 5 0
```

In a successful scenario there will be response code of 200 as shown below.

```
2019-11-11 05:34:42 ::1 POST /FlighterPhx/api/AbConfigOperations/GetABConfigBondFile env=1&abConfigId=147070852 80 - ::1 - - 401 2 5 0
2019-11-11 05:34:46 ::1 POST /FlighterPhx/api/AbConfigOperations/GetLatestABConfigId env=2&lineId=AdsFLN9 80 PHX\_toolsa ::1 - - 200 0 0 4734
```

Has any one faced this issue and what is the fix. Please help.

Comment: In the IIS logs, is the second request present? If not, the issue is with the client.

Comment: Enable Failed Request Tracing to get more information first.

Comment: @John the second request is not present. Lex yes I have already enabled logging. Please find the logs here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiE_72zIQiJzgbci9Wci0zqpDgfNdQ?e=NbwSx7